# Execute the javascript when button is pressed from html code?

Tags: javascript

I write a game in java script but problem is that when i launch the game from HTML page it starts the game directly. I need to start the game when start button is pressed and stop the game when stop button is pressed. The button is available but they didn't perform the start and stop action.The game is working fine but how i achieve these 2 mechanism in my HTML code?

1) Start game when start button is pressed?

2) stop game when stop button is pressed?

My javascript code :

```
    // 'notes' to store Arrows  


var notes = [];


// ==== CLASS FOR ARROWS ==== //

// 1. Direction of arrows
// 2. jQuery img that links to direction bottom
// 3. Destroy when it arrow gets to the 
// 4. Explode when arrow gets to the bottom

// Class Arrow
function Arrow(direction) {

    // CSS spacings for the arrows //
    var xPos = null;

    switch(direction) {

        case "left" : xPos = "350px";
        break;

        case "up" : xPos = "420px";
        break;

        case "down" : xPos = "490px";
        break;

        case "right" : xPos = "560px";
        break;

    }

    this.direction = direction;
    this.image = $("<img src='./arrows/" + direction + ".gif'/>");
    this.image.css({

        position: "absolute",
        top: "0px",
        left: xPos

    });

    $('.stage').append(this.image);

}// ends CLASS Arrow

// To enable animating the arrows
Arrow.prototype.step = function() {

    // Controls the speed of the arrows
    this.image.css("top", "+=4px");

};

// Deletes arrows when they get to bottom of page
Arrow.prototype.destroy = function() {

    // removes the image of the DOM
    this.image.remove();

    // Removes the note/arrow from memory/array
    notes.splice(0,1);

};

// Explodes arrow when hit
Arrow.prototype.explode = function() {

    this.image.remove();

};



// For random arrows
var randNum = 0;

// Frame increasing
var frame = 0;

// Determines the speed of notes
var arrowSpawnRate = 40;


// Random generator for arrows
function randomGen() {

    // Randomizes between 1 and 4
    randNum = Math.floor(Math.random() * 4) + 1;

    if (randNum === 1) {

        notes.push(new Arrow("left"));

    }
    if (randNum === 2) {

        notes.push(new Arrow("right"));

    }
    if (randNum === 3) {

        notes.push(new Arrow("up"));

    }
    if (randNum === 4) {

        notes.push(new Arrow("down"));

    }

}// ends randomGen()


// Render function //
function render() {

    if (frame++ % arrowSpawnRate === 0) {

        randomGen();

    }

    // Animate arrows showering down //
    for (var i = notes.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {

        notes[i].step();

        // Check for cleanup
        if (notes[i].image.position().top > 615) {

            notes[i].destroy();

        }

    }

}// ends render()



// jQuery to animate arrows //
$(document).ready(function () {

    // shim layer with setTimeout fallback
    window.requestAnimFrame = (function() {

        return window.requestAnimationFrame ||

        window.webkitRequestAnimationFrame ||

        window.mozRequestAnimationFrame ||

        function(callback) {

            window.setTimeout(callback, 40 / 75);

        };

    })();

    /*  place the rAF *before* the render() 
        to assure as close to 60fps with the 
        setTimeout fallback.                    */

    // Infinte loop for game play
    (function animloop() {

        requestAnimFrame(animloop);

        render();

    })();// ends (function animloop() )


});// ends $(doc).ready



// Listening for when the key is pressed
$(document).keydown( function(event) {

    for (var i = 0; i < notes.length; i++) {

            console.log(notes[i].image.position().top);

        if (event.keyCode == 37 && notes[i].direction == "left") {

            if (notes[i].image.position().top > 490 && notes[i].image.position().top < 730) {

                console.log("LEFT! "+notes[i].explode());

            }

        }
        if (event.keyCode == 38 && notes[i].direction == "up") {

            if (notes[i].image.position().top > 490 && notes[i].image.position().top < 730) {

                console.log("UP! "+notes[i].explode());

            }

        }
        if (event.keyCode == 40 && notes[i].direction == "down") {

            if (notes[i].image.position().top > 490 && notes[i].image.position().top < 730) {

                console.log("DOWN! "+notes[i].explode());

            }

        }
        if (event.keyCode == 39 && notes[i].direction == "right") {

            if (notes[i].image.position().top > 490 && notes[i].image.position().top < 730) {

                console.log("RIGHT! "+notes[i].explode());

            }

        }

    }// ends loop

});// ends $(doc).keyup
```

and HTML code:

```
<html>
<head>
    <link rel="icon" href="./arrows/clubbackground.jpg" type="image/gif" sizes="16x16">
    <script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.2.min.js"></script>
    <script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-migrate-1.2.1.min.js"></script>
    <script src="jsRev.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
    <script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.2.min.js"></script>
    <script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-migrate-1.2.1.min.js"></script>
    <title>DDR-Project 1</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="BackgroundScene">
        <div id="DanceScoreboard">
            <div id="GameStopped"><button id="StartBtn" class="btnStyle">Begin Game</button>
                <br><br><br><div class="Status">Click Begin Game to start</div>
            </div>
            <div id="GameRunning"><button id="StopBtn" class="btnStyle">Stop Game</button>
                <div id="Status" class="Status"></div>
            </div>
            <div id="dancePoints" class="Points">Points Earned: <div class="OutputText" id="CorrectCount">0</div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="stage"></div> <!-- ENDS .STAGE -->
        <div id="controls">
            <img id="left" src="./arrows/staticLeft.png">
            <img id="up" src="./arrows/staticUp.png">
            <img id="down" src="./arrows/staticDown.png">
            <img id="right" src="./arrows/staticRight.png">
        </div> <!-- ENDS #CONTROLS -->

</body>
</html>
```

HTML Picture :

[![enter image description here][1]][1]

The arrow start coming down without pressing the begin game button?

```js
// 'notes' to store Arrows  


var notes = [];

let isStarted = false;
// ==== CLASS FOR ARROWS ==== //

// 1. Direction of arrows
// 2. jQuery img that links to direction bottom
// 3. Destroy when it arrow gets to the 
// 4. Explode when arrow gets to the bottom

// Class Arrow
function Arrow(direction) {

    // CSS spacings for the arrows //
    var xPos = null;

    switch(direction) {

        case "left" : xPos = "350px";
        break;

        case "up" : xPos = "420px";
        break;

        case "down" : xPos = "490px";
        break;

        case "right" : xPos = "560px";
        break;

    }

    this.direction = direction;
    this.image = $("<img src='./arrows/" + direction + ".gif'/>");
    this.image.css({

        position: "absolute",
        top: "0px",
        left: xPos

    });

    $('.stage').append(this.image);

}// ends CLASS Arrow

// To enable animating the arrows
Arrow.prototype.step = function() {

    // Controls the speed of the arrows
    this.image.css("top", "+=4px");

};

// Deletes arrows when they get to bottom of page
Arrow.prototype.destroy = function() {

    // removes the image of the DOM
    this.image.remove();

    // Removes the note/arrow from memory/array
    notes.splice(0,1);

};

// Explodes arrow when hit
Arrow.prototype.explode = function() {

    this.image.remove();

};



// For random arrows
var randNum = 0;

// Frame increasing
var frame = 0;

// Determines the speed of notes
var arrowSpawnRate = 40;


// Random generator for arrows
function randomGen() {

    // Randomizes between 1 and 4
    randNum = Math.floor(Math.random() * 4) + 1;

    if (randNum === 1) {

        notes.push(new Arrow("left"));

    }
    if (randNum === 2) {

        notes.push(new Arrow("right"));

    }
    if (randNum === 3) {

        notes.push(new Arrow("up"));

    }
    if (randNum === 4) {

        notes.push(new Arrow("down"));

    }

}// ends randomGen()


// Render function //
function render() {

    if (frame++ % arrowSpawnRate === 0) {

        randomGen();

    }

    // Animate arrows showering down //
    for (var i = notes.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {

        notes[i].step();

        // Check for cleanup
        if (notes[i].image.position().top > 615) {

            notes[i].destroy();

        }

    }

}// ends render()



// jQuery to animate arrows //
$(document).ready(function () {

    // shim layer with setTimeout fallback
    window.requestAnimFrame = (function() {

        return window.requestAnimationFrame ||

        window.webkitRequestAnimationFrame ||

        window.mozRequestAnimationFrame ||

        function(callback) {

            window.setTimeout(callback, 40 / 75);

        };

    })();

    /*  place the rAF *before* the render() 
        to assure as close to 60fps with the 
        setTimeout fallback.                    */

    // Infinte loop for game play
    (function animloop() {

        if(requestAnimFrame(animloop));
        // ------------ Change is made here ----------
        if(isStarted){
           render();
        }

    })();// ends (function animloop() )


});// ends $(doc).ready



// Listening for when the key is pressed
$(document).keydown( function(event) {

    for (var i = 0; i < notes.length; i++) {

            console.log(notes[i].image.position().top);

        if (event.keyCode == 37 && notes[i].direction == "left") {

            if (notes[i].image.position().top > 490 && notes[i].image.position().top < 730) {

                console.log("LEFT! "+notes[i].explode());

            }

        }
        if (event.keyCode == 38 && notes[i].direction == "up") {

            if (notes[i].image.position().top > 490 && notes[i].image.position().top < 730) {

                console.log("UP! "+notes[i].explode());

            }

        }
        if (event.keyCode == 40 && notes[i].direction == "down") {

            if (notes[i].image.position().top > 490 && notes[i].image.position().top < 730) {

                console.log("DOWN! "+notes[i].explode());

            }

        }
        if (event.keyCode == 39 && notes[i].direction == "right") {

            if (notes[i].image.position().top > 490 && notes[i].image.position().top < 730) {

                console.log("RIGHT! "+notes[i].explode());

            }

        }

    }// ends loop

});// ends $(doc).keyup

const startButton = document.getElementById('StartBtn');
const stopButton = document.getElementById('StopBtn');

startButton.onclick = function(){
   isStarted = true;
}
stopButton.onclick = function(){
   isStarted = false;
}
```

```css
.stage {
 width: 1150px;    
 height: 500px;
 margin:0;
 padding:0;
    background-image: url('./arrows/clubbackground.jpg');
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: contain;
    position: relative;
 text-align: center;
 opacity: 90%;
 
}

#controls {
 padding-left: 350px;

}
/*#left {

}
#up {

}
#down {

}
#right {

}*/
.btnStyle {
 border-radius: 4px;
 border: medium solid #000000;
 background-color:rgb(92, 250, 246);
 font-family: "Arial", Impact, Charcoal, sans-serif;
 font-weight: bold;
 font-size:20px;
    color: #ffffff;
 padding: 5px 30px;
 margin:8px 70px;
}

#StartBtn{
 position: fixed;
 left: 100px;
    text-shadow: 2px 2px 4px black;
}

#StopBtn{
    position: fixed;
 left: 500px;
 down: 10px;
    border-radius: 4px;
 border: medium solid #000000;
 background-color:rgb(92, 250, 246);
 font-family: "Arial", Impact, Charcoal, sans-serif;
 font-weight: bold;
 font-size:20px;
    color: #ffffff;
    text-shadow: 2px 2px 4px black;
 padding: 5px 30px;
 margin:8px 70px;
}
```

```html
<html>
<head>
    <link rel="icon" href="./arrows/clubbackground.jpg" type="image/gif" sizes="16x16">
    <script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.2.min.js"></script>
    <script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-migrate-1.2.1.min.js"></script>
    <script src="jsRev.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
    <script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.2.min.js"></script>
    <script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-migrate-1.2.1.min.js"></script>
    <title>DDR-Project 1</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="BackgroundScene">
        <div id="DanceScoreboard">
            <div id="GameStopped"><button id="StartBtn" class="btnStyle">Begin Game</button>
                <br><br><br><div class="Status">Click Begin Game to start</div>
            </div>
            <div id="GameRunning"><button id="StopBtn" class="btnStyle">Stop Game</button>
                <div id="Status" class="Status"></div>
            </div>
            <div id="dancePoints" class="Points">Points Earned: <div class="OutputText" id="CorrectCount">0</div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="stage"></div> <!-- ENDS .STAGE -->
        <div id="controls">
            <img id="left" src="./arrows/staticLeft.png">
            <img id="up" src="./arrows/staticUp.png">
            <img id="down" src="./arrows/staticDown.png">
            <img id="right" src="./arrows/staticRight.png">
        </div> <!-- ENDS #CONTROLS -->

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: One way is to declare a global variable and set and unset it in the button event. And check for the variable inside your game logic.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Modify your main javascript to recognise a gameStarted state:

```js
var notes = [];
var gameStarted = false;

...

    (function animloop() {

        if (gameStarted) {

            requestAnimFrame(animloop);

            render();

        } else {

            window.setTimeout(animloop, 1000); // check the state per second

        }

    })();// ends (function animloop() )
```

In the start / end button, add attribute like:

```
<button id="StartBtn" class="btnStyle" onclick="gameStarted=true;">
<button id="StopBtn" class="btnStyle" onclick="gameStarted=false;">
```

Whole Code:

```
<html>
<head>
    <link rel="icon" href="./arrows/clubbackground.jpg" type="image/gif" sizes="16x16">
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.2.min.js"></script>
    <script src="jsRev.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
    <title>DDR-Project 1</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="BackgroundScene">
        <div id="DanceScoreboard">
            <div id="GameStopped"><button id="StartBtn" class="btnStyle" onclick="gameStarted=true;">Begin Game</button>
                <br><br><br><div class="Status">Click Begin Game to start</div>
            </div>
            <div id="GameRunning"><button id="StopBtn" class="btnStyle" onclick="gameStarted=false;">Stop Game</button>
                <div id="Status" class="Status"></div>
            </div>
            <div id="dancePoints" class="Points">Points Earned: <div class="OutputText" id="CorrectCount">0</div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="stage"></div> <!-- ENDS .STAGE -->
        <div id="controls">
            <img id="left" src="./arrows/staticLeft.png">
            <img id="up" src="./arrows/staticUp.png">
            <img id="down" src="./arrows/staticDown.png">
            <img id="right" src="./arrows/staticRight.png">
        </div> <!-- ENDS #CONTROLS -->

</body>
</html>
```

```
// 'notes' to store Arrows  


var notes = [];
var gameStarted = false;


// ==== CLASS FOR ARROWS ==== //

// 1. Direction of arrows
// 2. jQuery img that links to direction bottom
// 3. Destroy when it arrow gets to the 
// 4. Explode when arrow gets to the bottom

// Class Arrow
function Arrow(direction) {

    // CSS spacings for the arrows //
    var xPos = null;

    switch(direction) {

        case "left" : xPos = "350px";
        break;

        case "up" : xPos = "420px";
        break;

        case "down" : xPos = "490px";
        break;

        case "right" : xPos = "560px";
        break;

    }

    this.direction = direction;
    this.image = $("<img src='./arrows/" + direction + ".gif'/>");
    this.image.css({

        position: "absolute",
        top: "0px",
        left: xPos

    });

    $('.stage').append(this.image);

}// ends CLASS Arrow

// To enable animating the arrows
Arrow.prototype.step = function() {

    // Controls the speed of the arrows
    this.image.css("top", "+=4px");

};

// Deletes arrows when they get to bottom of page
Arrow.prototype.destroy = function() {

    // removes the image of the DOM
    this.image.remove();

    // Removes the note/arrow from memory/array
    notes.splice(0,1);

};

// Explodes arrow when hit
Arrow.prototype.explode = function() {

    this.image.remove();

};



// For random arrows
var randNum = 0;

// Frame increasing
var frame = 0;

// Determines the speed of notes
var arrowSpawnRate = 40;


// Random generator for arrows
function randomGen() {

    // Randomizes between 1 and 4
    randNum = Math.floor(Math.random() * 4) + 1;

    if (randNum === 1) {

        notes.push(new Arrow("left"));

    }
    if (randNum === 2) {

        notes.push(new Arrow("right"));

    }
    if (randNum === 3) {

        notes.push(new Arrow("up"));

    }
    if (randNum === 4) {

        notes.push(new Arrow("down"));

    }

}// ends randomGen()


// Render function //
function render() {

    if (frame++ % arrowSpawnRate === 0) {

        randomGen();

    }

    // Animate arrows showering down //
    for (var i = notes.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {

        notes[i].step();

        // Check for cleanup
        if (notes[i].image.position().top > 615) {

            notes[i].destroy();

        }

    }

}// ends render()



// jQuery to animate arrows //
$(document).ready(function () {

    // shim layer with setTimeout fallback
    window.requestAnimFrame = (function() {

         return window.requestAnimationFrame ||

         window.webkitRequestAnimationFrame ||

         window.mozRequestAnimationFrame ||

         function(callback) {

            window.setTimeout(callback, 40 / 75);

        };

    })();

    /*  place the rAF *before* the render() 
        to assure as close to 60fps with the 
        setTimeout fallback.                    */

    // Infinte loop for game play
    (function animloop() {

        if (gameStarted) {

            requestAnimFrame(animloop);

            render();

        } else {

            window.setTimeout(animloop, 1000); // check the state per second

        }

    })();// ends (function animloop() )


});// ends $(doc).ready



// Listening for when the key is pressed
$(document).keydown( function(event) {

    for (var i = 0; i < notes.length; i++) {

            console.log(notes[i].image.position().top);

        if (event.keyCode == 37 && notes[i].direction == "left") {

            if (notes[i].image.position().top > 490 && notes[i].image.position().top < 730) {

                console.log("LEFT! "+notes[i].explode());

            }

        }
        if (event.keyCode == 38 && notes[i].direction == "up") {

            if (notes[i].image.position().top > 490 && notes[i].image.position().top < 730) {

                console.log("UP! "+notes[i].explode());

            }

        }
        if (event.keyCode == 40 && notes[i].direction == "down") {

            if (notes[i].image.position().top > 490 && notes[i].image.position().top < 730) {

                console.log("DOWN! "+notes[i].explode());

            }

        }
        if (event.keyCode == 39 && notes[i].direction == "right") {

            if (notes[i].image.position().top > 490 && notes[i].image.position().top < 730) {

                console.log("RIGHT! "+notes[i].explode());

            }

        }

    }// ends loop

});// ends $(doc).keyup
```

Comment: it still the same when i open html file the game started without pressing start button

Comment: Strange. I think you better 1. console.log(gameStarted) and 2. throw new Error() at the beginning of function render to know anything changed the gameStarted or the call stack to know whether something else than animloop is calling to render (hoping the first wrong call is a sync call).

Comment: will you please run it on your computer https://ufile.io/wmd0tesn .

Comment: my solution works on my side. Just need to remove the repeated jQuery inclusion in head. I think only one jQuery line is needed:
```HTML
<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.2.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: will you please send me your whole code?

Comment: pasted whole code in my answer here

Comment: your start and stop button is working fine ?

Comment: they works in some sense. The start to let the movement continue, the stop will pause the movement. Is this what you want?

Comment: yes but stop wil end the game not pause. Why not its working in my computer . Which IDE and browser you use ?

Comment: @LogitechFlames To end the game it definitely need more js code than the current one so I don't think it should be cover in this troubleshooting. My browser is Chrome 81. (IDE is Notepad++)

Comment: i think its my browser issue. Should we use Teamviewer ?

Comment: no. You can find another machine to try it. It's your own business man...

Comment: ok i try as you in code there is point i need to count the point when the arrows is pressed so i need to add the count++ when keys are pressed?

Comment: another recommendation is: you can try to disable all your browser plugins if you really cannot afford to find another device or another browser

Comment: i will try it if it is not work i post a comment

Comment: hm...for counting points, I think it is totally outside the original question and you should spend your effort to learn more about how to do it...

Answer (score 2):

Create a global variable `isStarted` and set it `false`

```
let isStarted = false;
```

Before calling the `render()` method check if `isStarted` is true or not.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
// shim layer with setTimeout fallback
window.requestAnimFrame = (function() {

    return window.requestAnimationFrame ||

    window.webkitRequestAnimationFrame ||

    window.mozRequestAnimationFrame ||

    function(callback) {

        window.setTimeout(callback, 40 / 75);

    };

})();

/*  place the rAF *before* the render() 
    to assure as close to 60fps with the 
    setTimeout fallback.                    */

// Infinte loop for game play
(function animloop() {

    requestAnimFrame(animloop);
    // ------------ Change is made here ----------
    if(isStarted){
       render();
    }


})();// ends (function animloop() )


});// ends $(doc).ready
```

Then add onclick events to the buttons and change `isStarted`

```
const startButton = document.getElementById('StartBtn');
const stopButton = document.getElementById('StopBtn');

startButton.onclick = function(){
   isStarted = true;
}
stopButton.onclick = function(){
   isStarted = false;
}
```

Comment: will you please change it in my code?

Comment: @LogitechFlames No I am here to help the people who want to learn. We are not here to provide code to someone. Try it yourself if you get an error tell me. Btw is above code your own or copied from somewhere else?

Comment: brah i wrote it come on

Comment: i did this but the same problem the game started without pressing start button

Comment: @LogitechFlames Try to add `requestAnimFrame(animloop);` inside the `if` block

Comment: i did it but still problem is same even if i do change you write. If you run it you will know the problem [link] https://ufile.io/wmd0tesn

Comment: there is some problem in html code i am sure because when i open up a page it start the game directly

Comment: @LogitechFlames Brother please create an html runnable snippet in your question to show the problem.

Comment: @LogitechFlames See this https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/358992/ive-been-told-to-create-a-runnable-example-with-stack-snippets-how-do-i-do if you don't know to create a snippet

Comment: check i update the question

Comment: @LogitechFlames I asked you create a runnable snippet to show the problem not the images of your game.

Comment: sorry now check it

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/209201/discussion-between-maheer-ali-and-logitech-flames).